# Why does the code below return an empty string (''")?

Tags: python, algorithm

I don't understand when you input the word "pandemonium", how does it return an empty string (""). Can someone explain why that is.

```
def mystery(text):
    result = ""
    for x in text:
        if x == "p":
            result += "pop"
        elif x == "m":
            result = ""
        else:
            result += x
    return result
```

Comment: `elif x == "m":` gets hit on the last letter of your word `pandemonium` which is resetting `result` to `""` which is what you get back

Comment: The last character in `pandemonium` is `m`, and your code sets `result` to empty for that. You are missing a `+` I guess.

Comment: "trace" your code! Would have provided you the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would have been trivial to figure out with some pen and paper, and there's no obvious problem to be answered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when `x == "m"` you reset the `result` variable to equal an empty string instead of appending it.

```
def mystery(text):
    result = ""
    for x in text:
        if x == "p":
            result += "pop"
        elif x == "m":
            result += ""
        else:
            result += x
    return result
```

Comment: `result` is not a list, so you can not append to it.

Comment: Your code doesn't return a string, but instead returns an array

Comment: OP never did stated that his code is correct or not, just wondering what's happening. You shouldn't modify existing behavior if it's not clearly stated.